# TFS 2017 Build Numbering

Tags: tfs

We have upgraded from TFS 2013 to TFS 2017, One feature we are trying to implement that we had in 2013 was the ability to have a custom build number. the previous method we had a file called BuildVersion.XML which during the first build step would read the major,minor, and revision and name the build with that build number + 1 on the revision. It would then change then checkout and update the revison number and check in the new version. I know that there are steps where people update the AssemblyInfo. The issue is that not all our code is .net apps. we also now have SSIS Packages, Cordova iOS/android apps, angular sites, aws Lambda functions with node.js which do not have the concept of AssemblyInfo. is there an easy way to implement this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do exactly the same thing in Team Build in TFS 2017.

You can update the build number from any task by calling:

```
Write-Verbose -Verbose "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]1.2.3.4"
```

Add a PowerShell task and add an inline script to read from your file and update the build number with the above.

You can then have additional scripts that use the build number any way you need to version your application.

You can see the full list of logging commands here
https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

Comment: ok so writing this command will update the build number of the build? '''Write-Verbose -Verbose "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]1.2.3.4". but i then want to increase the number and check-out the file, update the value and check it in again

Comment: @greektreat You can do all those steps inside a PowerShell script, and then call build.updatebuildnumber from within that same script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [VSTS TFVC tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-tfvc-tasks) to interact with source control, though I do not recommend it. I built these tasks for clients of mine who were doing exactly what you are doing.

Instead of relying on a file in source control it would be a much better solution to pass the BuildNumber from the Build Definition along to the build, have one of your first steps update the files on disk with the correct version number then run your build.

If you manipulate files during the build and check them in you run the risk of inconsistent numbering when you scale up to multiple build agents, it's hard to use in combination with parallel builds and build variable multiplexing and it becomes notoriously hard to do Gated Checkins and Shelveset builds. Plus, it limits your options to move to Git in the future.

Comment: we will not be able to pass in the build numbers. we have many developers (50+) working on many systems we need it fully automated. I had another thought is it possible to update my build variable automatically? i create a variable Build.minor = 1, when i do the build uppon success update it to 2 for the next build?

Comment: The number of developers is not really of influence... And the number of systems isn't either... You can use the rest api to query the previous build number and play with it using powershell. Then use the magic string provided by mrhinsh to write out the new number. You will still run into issues with parallel builds, gated builds, shelveset builds etc.